# How to avoid a nested for loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, vectorization

If I have :

```
for i=1:n
    for j=1:m
        if outputImg(i,j) < thresholdLow
            outputImg(i,j) = 0;
        elseif outputImg(i,j)> thresholdHigh
            outputImg(i,j) = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

or even worse :

```
for i=1:n
    for j=1:m
        for k=1:q
                % do something  
        end
    end
end
```

How can I achieve this differently , without `for` ?

Comment: The general answer to your question is "vectorize your code".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the first loop you can use logical conditions, such as:

```
 outputImg(outputImg<thresholdLow)=0;
 outputImg(outputImg>thresholdHigh)=1;
```

There are of course many other equivalent ways to get that using logical operators...

For the second loop you need to be more specific, but I think you got the grips of the logical conditions trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you use binary matrix:

```
index_matrix = (outputImg < thresholdLow);
```

The following hold:

```
index_matrix(i,j) == 0 iff outputImg(i,j) < thresholdLow
index_matrix(i,j) == 1 iff outputImg(i,j) > thresholdLow
```

[see also](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/answers/12022)

for the second loop you can always use matirx over for loop

Answer (score 1):

For a general solution, look into `ndgrid` which in your second case you could use like this:

```
[i j k] = ndgrid(1:n, 1:m, 1:q);
ijk = [i(:) j(:) k(:)];
```

Then you can traverse the list of combinations of `i`, `j`, and `k`, i.e. now `ijk` to parameterize your thresholding statements.

Comment: Actually, no need to define `ijk`. You can simply use one for loop to go through the length of `i` which is the same as the length of `k` and of `j` to index these vectors. This is perhaps what @Leonid Beschastny meant by vectorizing your code.

Comment: How to write this dynamically? for example we want to write the `[a1 a2 ... aN] = ndgrid(1:p);` for variable N's. How to do this?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi I think my answer is really not the best for the OP's question so perhaps you could post this as a separate one.